# How to verify F-relatedness?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

This question is from Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds p182. I would like to verify the following vector fields are F-related using two ways, i.e. confirming either $dF_p(X_p)=Y_{F(p)}$ for $\forall t\in\mathbb{R}$ or $X(f\circ F)=(Yf)\circ F$ for $\forall f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $f$ is real-valued. I'm not sure how to verify using the first way, so I would like to know that. For the second way, I made a solution, so I would like some suggestion if there's any point to be fixed.

[image]

$$X(f\circ F)=\frac{d}{dt}(f(\cos t,\sin t))=-\sin t f_x(\cos t,\sin t)+\cos t f_y(\cos t,\sin t)=(Yf)\circ F$$